# Regex in Python: How to match a word pattern, if not preceded by another word of variable length?

Tags: python, regex

I would like reconstruct full names from photo captions using Regex in Python, by appending last name back to the first name in patterns **"FirstName1 and FirstName2 LastName"**. We can rely on names starting with capital letter.

For example,

**'John and Albert McDonald'** becomes **'John McDonald'** and **'Albert McDonald'**

**'Stephen Stewart, John and Albert Diamond'** becomes **'John Diamond'** and **'Albert Diamond'**

I would need to avoid matching patterns like this: **'Jay Smith and Albert Diamond'** and generate a non-existent name **'Smith Diamond'**

The photo captions may or may not have more words before this pattern, for example, **'It was a great day hanging out with John and Stephen Diamond.'**

This is the code I have so far:

```
s = 'John and Albert McDonald'
so = re.search('([A-Z][a-z\-]+)\sand\s([A-Z][a-z\-]+\s[A-Z][a-z\-]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)?)', s)        
if so:
    print so.group(1) + ' ' + so.group(2).split()[1]
    print so.group(2)
```

This returns **'John McDonald'** and **'Albert McDonald'**, but **'Jay Smith and Albert Diamond'** will result in a non-existent name **'Smith Diamond'**.

An idea would be to check whether the pattern is preceded by a capitalized word, something like **`(?<![A-Z][a-z\-]+)`**`\s([A-Z][a-z\-]+)\sand\s([A-Z][a-z\-]+\s[A-Z][a-z\-]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)?)` but unfortunately negative lookbehind only works if we know the exact length of the preceding word, which I don't.

Could you please let me know how I can correct my regex epression? Or is there a better way to do what I want? Thanks!

Comment: Can you rely on the names starting with a big letter?

Comment: For a problem like this, you should write the test cases first.

Comment: @Vallentin Yes, we can rely on names starting with a capital letter.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Sorry I'm new to Python and not really familiar with unittest module for writing test cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can rely on names starting with a capital letter, then you could do something like:

```
((?:[A-Z]\w+\s+)+)and\s+((?:[A-Z]\w+(?:\s+|\b))+)
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/Pcr6XQ/1)

Swapping out your current pattern, with this pattern should work with your current Python code. *You do need to `strip()` the captured results though.*

Which for your examples and current code would yield:

```
Input
First print
Second print

John and Albert McDonald
John McDonald
Albert McDonald

Stephen Stewart, John and Albert Diamond
John Diamond
Albert Diamond

It was a great day hanging out with John and Stephen Diamond.
John Diamond
Stephen Diamond
```